# bad SQL grammar - Java JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to query the database using the following SQL :

```
select round(b.Used_space*100/a.tablespace_size,2)
from
(select tablespace_name,sum(bytes/1024/1024/1024) tablespace_size, sum(decode(MAXBYTES,0,bytes/1024/1024/1024,MAXBYTES/1024/1024/1024)) max_tablespace_size
 from dba_temp_files group by tablespace_name) a,
(select x.TABLESPACE tablespace_name,sum(x.blocks*y.block_size/1024/1024/1024) used_space from v$sort_usage x , dba_tablespaces y where x.tablespace=y.tablespace_name group by x.TABLESPACE)  b
where a.tablespace_name=b.tablespace_name (+);
```

When run in oracle it works fine. When i try to execute the query from java i get "bad sql grammar".

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select a.tablespace_name,a.tablespace_size Allocated_space_IN_GB, round(b.Used_space,2) Used_Space_in_GB, round(b.Used_space*100/a.tablespace_size,2) "Used%", a.max_tablespace_size MAX_tablespace_size_IN_GB ,round(b.used_space*100/a.max_tablespace_size,2) "Max_Alloc_Used%" from (select tablespace_name,sum(bytes/1024/1024/1024) tablespace_size, sum(decode(MAXBYTES,0,bytes/1024/1024/1024,MAXBYTES/1024/1024/1024)) max_tablespace_size  from dba_temp_files group by tablespace_name) a, (select x.TABLESPACE tablespace_name,sum(x.blocks*y.block_size/1024/1024/1024) used_space from v$sort_usage x , dba_tablespaces y where x.tablespace=y.tablespace_name group by x.TABLESPACE)  b where a.tablespace_name=b.tablespace_name (+)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

What am i missing?

Comment: show us the regarding java code...

Comment: You should stop using the (deprecated) Oracle specific outer join operator `(+)` in the implicit joins of the `where` clause and start using explicit joins using the `OUTER JOIN` operator

Comment: try it with database_name.table

Comment: You haven't shown us you relating Java code. However, from that error, Java can't find your table. Are you connecting to your database correctly in Java?

Comment: is your java app connecting as the same user as the one you run in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that the oracle login you are using when running the java is different than the one you are using when you run the query in oracle. If this is the case, then one of these is probably the answer:

1. The java login probabaly does not have select priviledge on the table or view in question.
2. The java login schema is not the same as the oracle login schema (them being different logins and all) and there is no synonym for the table (or tables) in the query in the java login.  If this is the case, add schema to the table names (ex.  blammy.table_name).

Based on the tables you are using (dba_temp_blah), I suspect 1 is the anser.